# jQuery - concurrency?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery

After a certain event, I need to populate several data tables. Each table has an associated API method on the server that needs to be called in order to get its data. I don't want to make these API calls one at a time. Is there a way to do this concurrently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fire off the XHR requests for the data one after another they'll be processed asynchronously which will I think achieve the same thing e.g.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "dataSourceA",
  success: function(){
    // populate data table A
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: "dataSourceB",
  success: function(){
    // populate data table B
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: "dataSourceC",
  success: function(){
    // populate data table C
  }
});
```

Although the calls above are made in a sequence, the asynchronous behaviour of the underlying XHR requests means that the success callbacks won't necessarily be called in the order above - they'll be called in the order in which the server processes the requests - I think from your question that this is what you want...

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to make AJAX requests arrive at the server in a specified order unless you wait for one to finish before sending the next one.